# In iOS 7, using UIModalPresentationCurrentContext for an animated modal presentation doesn't animate

Tags: ios, animation, ios7, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

In iOS 8, when presenting a modal (lets say with a transparent background), we need to set the segue (or the modal) to use the presentation style of `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`. This is working as expected.

To accomplish the same thing for iOS 7, you instead, need to set the presenting view controller to have a modal presentation style of `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`. Here's where I'm having an issue. I present the modal with animation, but it doesn't animate. After it is presented, everything works fine, even animating the dismissal. Further, if I change the presentation style to `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`, it animates correctly.

I've searched around and read other posts, but I can't find the cause of this or a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
  ViewController *vcObj = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([ViewController class]) bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vcObj];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 8.0) {

        navCon.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
        navCon.definesPresentationContext = YES;
        navCon.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

        [self presentViewController:navCon animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
    else {

        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [self presentViewController:navCon animated:NO completion:^{
            [navCon dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
                appDelegate.window.rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
                [self presentViewController:navCon animated:NO completion:nil];
                appDelegate.window.rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

            }];
        }];
    }
```